# Enable VNC Server on Linux

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc

Searched in the menu but cant find it

Comment: What distribution and version?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?  what distribution are you using?  as-is this is not enough detail to answer.  there are many different ways to use VNC.  are you looking to share an existing desktop?  [share a single application?](http://superuser.com/questions/153903/how-to-setup-vnc-on-linux) [run VNC on a headless server](http://superuser.com/questions/136785/run-vino-without-a-monitor-ubuntu-10-04) or [automatically start VNC server at startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/147109/automatically-start-vnc-server-on-startup)

Comment: Well someone modified my question title from Leeenux to Linux.

The distribution is Leeenux.  http://www.leeenux-linux.com/

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to download and install a vnc server from your distribution's repositories. On debian-based distributions, you should be able to use `sudo apt-get install vnc-server` or `sudo apt-get install vnc4server`.

Answer (score 1):

Many distributions of linux come with VNC built in. If you are using Ubuntu, you can share your desktop by going to System > Preferences > Remote Desktop and enabling the vino VNC server from there. Darth Android's method lets you have multiple computers connect to multiple sessions on the same computer which is also quite useful.